# simple question: does $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$ and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}b_n$ converge?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

If $0 < a_n + b_n\leq c_n$ $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$, and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} c_n$ converges, then does $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$ and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}b_n$ converge?

I think it's true, because it is bounded by 0, and $c_n$ converges, so $a_n, b_n$ converge.

If $0 < a_n \leq b_n+c_n$ $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$, and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$ diverge, then both $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}b_n$, $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}c_n$ converge?

I think this one is similar to the contrapositive of the other one. It seems to be true as well then.

Comment: Without the constraint that $a_n, b_n$ are individually greater than zero then the first one is false — consider $a_n=-n, b_n=n+\frac1{n^2}$.

Comment: The 1st one holds if you assume $a_n\ge 0$ and $b_n\ge 0$ but it does hold in general. It's like asking "If $c$ is near $0$ and $0<a+b\le c$, are $a$ and $b$ near $0$?" Maybe not, if $a<0<b$.

Answer (score 1):

The next one is not true. For $a_{n}=1/n$, $b_{n}=a_{n}$, $c_{n}=1/n^{2}$.

Comment: We could also have $b_n=a_n$ and $c_n=0$.

Answer (score 0):

Take $a_n=1$, $b_n=-1+1/n^2, c_n=2/n^2$ for the first case and for the second case, take $a_n=1/n,b_n=1/n^2, c_n=1/n+2/n^2$ for counter-examples.